# Switching image src with images from an array on an interval in React

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

This should be fairly simple, but I keep getting a weird behaviour from the result.

Basically, I have an array of images:

```
  const images = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6];
```

I also have an image index:

```
  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);
```

Then I do a little incrementation of the index:

```
const switchImage = () => {
if (imageIndex === images.length - 1) {
  setImageIndex(0);
} else {
  setImageIndex(imageIndex + 1);
}
return imageIndex;
}
```

Then I call this function from a useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
setInterval(() => {
  switchImage();
}, 1000);
 }, []);
```

And finally I add the html:

```
<img src={images[imageIndex]} />
```

The result is usually it gets stuck on the second image and stops incrementing, so I thought the issue might be with the useEffect and the way the component is rendering.

Comment: I have a feeling the `switchImage` is defined so that it has stale value, as in, whenever it is called, it sees `imageIndex` being `0`, so it adds 1 to it, you end up with always seeing the second image. If you provide a more complete code snippet, I can help you with a fix.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the second method signature of the  `useState` setter function which gives you the *previous* state value to avoid the stale closure captured value.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
const images = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];

const Thing =()=>{
  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setImageIndex(prev => (
        prev === images.length - 1 ? 0 : prev + 1
      ));
    }, 1000);
  },[])

  console.log(imageIndex)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{images[imageIndex]}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

  root.render(<Thing  />);
```

See here https://codepen.io/drGreen/pen/JjpmQrV

Also worth seeing this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-every-react-developer-should-know-about-state/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20stale%20state%20in,variable%20from%20an%20outer%20scope.) which is virtually identical.

Comment: Thanks! This is the working solution.

Answer (score -2):

In your case the useEffect which you have created it is only being triggered once; when the component is loading - that is because you did not define when this logic should be triggered by adding dependencies to the useEffect.

Now, since the component renders once, 'switchImage'()' is only being triggered once, hence, it iterates once, display the img and stops.

Here is some good documentation on useEffect if you would like to read more about it [Using the Effect Hook - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

**Here is a slightly altered solution where we are using the debounce technique for the timer**. [SOLUTION](https://codepen.io/sergiunimat/pen/eYVPqVY?editors=1111)

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

const images = ['','','','','',''];

const DemoComponent = () =>{
const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = React.useState(0);

//debounce set default 0.3s
const debounce = (func, timeout = 300) =>{
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}

// switch img fn.
const switchImage = () => {
  setImageIndex(imageIndex === images.length - 1 ? 0 : imageIndex + 1)
  return imageIndex;
}

//debounce switchImage and set timer to 1s
const switchImageDebounce = debounce(() => switchImage(),1000);

//useEffect  
React.useEffect(() => {
    switchImageDebounce()
}, [imageIndex]);

return (
  <div>
    <h1>{images[imageIndex]}</h1>
  </div>
);
```

}

root.render();

Comment: This is not good. If you set an interval in an effect for each change of `imageIndex` you  end up with many many intervals, it's not a timeout.

Comment: well perhaps, however, the original issue was that the img are not being rendered after the second time - am I correct? - I merely just suggested how to solve that issue, if you would like to solve the 'timer' issue, then you would use the debounce/throtle technique.

Comment: No, you are not correct. You are creating an infinite amount of intervals. Each interval would cause `imageIndex` to change, which would cause new interval to spawn. After 10 seconds, you have 10 intervals running. Check the difference between intervals and timeouts.

Comment: I have updated my response, have a look. I would like you to define 'Infinite' and also how an infinite amount of intervals are being created, that doesn't really make any sense.

And if you know React, there is mounting and unmounting of a component (i assume that would be the spawn that you mentioned), meaning that once we update the imageIndex useState the component is re-rendered and not kept in the background to run as you described.

Comment: You have an effect that re-runs based on `imageIndex` and inside this effect, you create an interval. After one second the interval is run and it changes `imageIndex`. That results in the effect being called again and a new interval is created. Now you have two intervals, after another second, both of them change the `imageIndex`, causing two react rerenders because intervals are not batched. Now you have 4 intervals. So I was wrong before, it's not 10 intervals after 10 seconds, it's exponential.

Comment: yes, I have read this article https://upmostly.com/tutorials/setinterval-in-react-components-using-hooks and you are right. However, the solution which I have posted handles this issue in the debounce function.